# C# mono inter process, inter application cross platform messaging implementation. (How to)

Tags: cross-platform, messaging, pipe, anonymous, interprocess

I am developing applications and c#, I at the moment, I work on projects for Windows Platform only. However, I am planning to move into using C# mono to make my programs be able to work with linux, mac-os and windows.

One of the feature I am implementing in my program is the ability to communicate between them (ie. A Console type program that can communicate and interact with GUI Program by sending commands and receiving reply messages, logging messages, signals,.etc). Back in windows dotnet framework, I am looking at anonymous pipes, but now, I am checking if Mono.Unix.UnixPipes will do the job for me and will let me implement inter process messaging with very little to no adjustments at all under linux, mac-os and windows.

I am a little bit new to this kind of feature, and i am now reading into the documentations (however, class and objects documentations are not helping me so much yet). I am also browsing to some of the inter process messaging questions that are posted here in stackoverflow.

If anyone has a link to a tutorial kind of document or example on how to do this, it will be a great help. please help?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend running a mongodb (easly scalable from a dev boxes to hundreds of servers) and using the library https://github.com/dominionenterprises/mongo-queue-csharp on top of it for the messaging. It has the ability to query for messages which enables some really nice patterns. Also its compatible with mono ! Also has some other languages if needed down the road.